# Positioning vertically center aligned navigation arrows to the left and right of an image

Tags: html, css

How can I get the percentage declaration to work (`#case-left, #case-right`)..?

My goal is to align these these two elements to the left and right of the image respectively, always 50% from the top of the image.

As shown in the image below:

[image: desired output]

As far as I can tell, my `#nav-container` element isn't high enough.

HTML:

```
<div id="case-example-cover">
    <div id="nav-container">
        <div id="case-left"></div>
        <div id="case-right"></div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://s7.directupload.net/images/140625/yflekqdc.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#case-example-cover {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}

#case-example-cover #nav-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 980px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#case-example-cover #case-left {
    background-image: url("http://s7.directupload.net/images/140625/lhmdzrfd.png");
    float: right;
    height: 38px;
    width: 38px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:50%;
}

#case-example-cover #case-right {
    background-image: url("http://s7.directupload.net/images/140625/lhmdzrfd.png");
    height: 38px;
    width: 38px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top:50%;
}

#case-example-cover img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Check out my current sample at [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H65FD/)

Comment: confusing for me atleast what you want to achieve

Comment: "this two elements are always 50% from the top of the image" - 50% above, below, right, or left..? "And always left and right zero" left and right of what..? can you be more specific and improve the description so that it's understandable..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy look at this. I hope this helps you to understand: http://s7.directupload.net/images/140625/rsxxj3ji.jpg

Comment: @MichAel i've edited the question to be more understandable, if i missed something, please update. hope the answer helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `height` specified in `%` won't work if the parent element does not have a `height` set explicitly, So you need to set height for `html` and `body`
- `float` has no effect on `absolute` positioned elements
- the selector `#case-example-cover #case-right` can simply be `#case-right` since `id` is unique in a document

HTML

```
<div id="case-example-cover">
  <div id="nav-container">
    <div id="case-left"></div>
    <div id="case-right"></div>
    <img src="http://s7.directupload.net/images/140625/yflekqdc.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
 height:100%;
}
#case-example-cover {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin-top: 80px;
}
#nav-container {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 980px;
}
#nav-container div{
 position: absolute;
 top: -webkit-calc(50% - 19px);
 top: -moz-calc(50% - 19px);
 top: -ms-calc(50% - 19px);
 top: calc(50% - 19px);
 width: 38px;
 height: 38px;
 background-image: url("http://s7.directupload.net/images/140625/lhmdzrfd.png");
}
#case-left { 
 left: 0;
}
#case-right {
 right: 0;
}
#case-example-cover img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H65FD/7/)

**Update**

For center aligning the icons container based on the image container that is of variable width, you need to position it absolutely relative to the image container and apply

```
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
```

to create a block, then apply `margin:auto;`

Then you can position the left and right icons inside it as mentioned above.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H65FD/15/)

*Side notes: the scroll is due to the borders i've added in demo since i can't see the images (maybe it's blocked in my network).*

Comment: I need the image width 100% browser width. with your code, the image width is max 980px.

Comment: i didn't get it. the icons container has `max-width:980px` and you want the icons to be on the exact left and right side of the image. then how could the image be larger than icons container..? if you want it to be `100%` of browser window, then why the  `max-width:980px`?

Comment: @MichAel oh i get it, you need an image that is of `100%` width, and a     another section above it whose maximum width will be `980px`. Check the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H65FD/15/embedded/result/). So, do you want the `#case-example-cover` to be as height as the image, or `100%` of the window..?

Comment: Thats it! The #case-example-cover should have the height of the image. Because there will be other elements under it (text, images, list, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Move the image inside the container div. Also assign the top property like below.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="case-example-cover">
    <div id="nav-container">
        <div id="case-left"></div>
        <div id="case-right"></div>
        <img src="http://s7.directupload.net/images/140625/yflekqdc.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#case-example-cover #case-left {
background-image: url("http://s7.directupload.net/images/140625/lhmdzrfd.png");
float: right;
height: 38px;
width: 38px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top:calc(50% - 19px);
}

#case-example-cover #case-right {
background-image: url("http://s7.directupload.net/images/140625/lhmdzrfd.png");
height: 38px;
width: 38px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top:calc(50% - 19px);
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/H65FD/5/)

Comment: @SuresPonnukalai   I need the image width with 100% browser-width. So i mov ethe image in #nav-container ist limited to 980px.

Comment: I don't see anything in the output window… is it just me..? (*maybe the images are blocked in my network. but i don't see any request failures*)

Comment: @Mich Ael so your bullet icons maximum width is 980px? No need to show in the edge of the image?

Comment: @SuresPonnukalai Yes. The Image should be 100% width of the browser. the bullet icons container should be 980px, centered and above the image. and the bullet icons should be at the left and right edge inside the 980px container.

Comment: This must be the accepted answer, it shows how to calculate the top size using calc(50% - height/2 px).